# Compiling an entire CMAF (.cmfv and .cmfa) stream into mp4

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to create a general-purpose media downloader in Python which can download online media streams and compile them into one video file (ideally .mp4).

I've encountered media streams using the CMAF format in which a server breaks up complete video files into pieces (video files “.cmfv” and audio files “.cmfa”) and then streams them to the client as they view the content.

**I can download all of the individual files, but I am having trouble putting them back together into one video. That is the problem I’m trying to solve**

I've tried looping through each of the video files (.cmfv) and writing them all into a new file. After combining, I tried to use FFMPEG to convert the combined .cmfv to mp4. I get an ffmpeg error that the combined .cmfv file cannot be read.

```
# python

# create empty cmfv file
oldcmfv = open(“somepath”, “w”)

# iterate through individual cmfv files
for file in folder:
    with open(file) as portion:
        # write the cmfv portion to the combined cmfv file
        oldcmfv.write(portion)

oldcmfv.close()

# mp4 path
newmp4 = “somepath”

# attempt to convert cmfv combined file to mp4
# note that I did not try to include the cmfa (audio) files
ffmpeg.output(newmp4).input(oldcmfv).run()
```

As a side note, it seems that there is very little discussion/information about the CMAF format. There is a technical document published by Apple and one other informational article that I saw but it seems like most resources are explaining how to encode videos into CMAF, but not how to decode them. I found an amazing GitHub repo that downloads CMAF stream media files pretty much automatically, but piecing them together has been a mystery so far.

Comment: Is this solved now? Can you share your solution, or you still need one?

Comment: @VC.One Yes - sort of. I decided to let FFMPEG handle the entire process of downloading/compiling the mp4. Here is the command (using python subprocess): ```subprocess.run(f"ffmpeg -y -i \"{url_to_cmaf_file}\" -codec copy -movflags faststart -f mp4 {download_path}")```     **I have found that it is critical to include the 'movflags fastart' parameter in your call or else video players can't read the resulting file. something about where the metadata is stored in the mp4 file.** Hope this helps!